# Change "activate_url" in email confirmation in django allauth

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

The email is being sent from the template **email_confirmation_message.txt**

```
{% load account %}{% user_display user as user_display %}{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Hello from {{ site_name }}!

You're receiving this e-mail because user {{ user_display }} has given yours as an e-mail address to connect their account.

To confirm this is correct, go to {{ activate_url }}
{% endblocktrans %}{% endautoescape %}
{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Thank you from {{ site_name }}!
{{ site_domain }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

The activate_url is sending link as http://web/en/accounts/confirm-email/Mjc:1fWFRw:q-ScRb0Wnsrrem9N7pB9iLOuPOM/  where web is my conatiner hostname. How can I change this to custom domain name without having to change my conatiner hostname. I am using **django-allauth==0.33.0**

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to change your domain. It uses your own site domain.

`activate_url` is from `get_email_confirmation_url()`.

```
 activate_url = self.get_email_confirmation_url(
 ...


def get_email_confirmation_url(self, request, emailconfirmation):
    url = reverse(
        "account_confirm_email",
        args=[emailconfirmation.key])
    ret = build_absolute_uri(
        request,
        url)
    return ret
```

You can see code [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/b31eaf50bd8553052429240388d95607d6e73a17/allauth/account/adapter.py#L429) (allauth gihtub code).

and it use `build_absolute_uri` from allatuh.utils.

here's the code.

```
def build_absolute_uri(request, location, protocol=None):
    from .account import app_settings as account_settings

    if request is None:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
        bits = urlsplit(location)
        if not (bits.scheme and bits.netloc):
            uri = '{proto}://{domain}{url}'.format(
                proto=account_settings.DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL,
                domain=site.domain,
                url=location)
        else:
            uri = location
    else:
        uri = request.build_absolute_uri(location)
    # NOTE: We only force a protocol if we are instructed to do so
    # (via the `protocol` parameter, or, if the default is set to
    # HTTPS. The latter keeps compatibility with the debatable use
    # case of running your site under both HTTP and HTTPS, where one
    # would want to make sure HTTPS links end up in password reset
    # mails even while they were initiated on an HTTP password reset
    # form.
    if not protocol and account_settings.DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL == 'https':
        protocol = account_settings.DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL
    # (end NOTE)
    if protocol:
        uri = protocol + ':' + uri.partition(':')[2]
    return uri
```

You can find this code [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/utils.py#L253)

Comment: Thank you @seuling your answer helped me. Basically I used regex lib to replace the hostname in the activate_url string.